# Accessing decommissioned website in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I have a website that we used to access via Umbraco. It was decommissioned on 11/22 to a new site with same name.  There is some content we need to retrieve. I was thinking maybe we could access it via IP but that doesn't work. Anyone know how to accomplish this so we can log on to the old site via umbraco without interfering with the new site.

Comment: Have you contacted the hosting company?

Answer (score 0):

If you log into the server and find the site in IIS, you could set up new bindings on that site, so it responds to `decommissioned.mysite.com`. Then add a host file entry to your local machine, so `decommissioned.mysite.com` sends you to your decommissioned site.

When your computer performs a DNS lookup, the host file is the first place it will look. This means you can use the host file to bypass the DNS settings configured for the public. It comes in handy when you have a dev version of a site that isn't ready for the world, yet. On windows you can find the host file at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. You will probably need to run your text editor as an administrator to edit the file. This is what host file entries look like:

```
123.123.123.123 mydomain.com www.mydomain.com
321.321.321.321 www.myotherdomain.com blog.myotherdomain.com
```

Comment: I host my own dns so I set a new host record in my dns called legacy
In my IIS I bound the dns entry.
Refreshed IIS and now I can get to decommissioned site. Thanks!